# get input value through its parent div id

Tags: jquery, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following markup:

```js
(function( $ ) {
 'use strict';

 function format_number_two_decimal(number) {
  return parseFloat(Math.round(number * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
 }

 function calculartotal(){
  var importe_neto = document.getElementById("acf-field_58c13e2ed4e42").value;
  var importe_total = importe_neto * 1.21;
  importe_total = format_number_two_decimal( importe_total) ;

  $("input#acf-field_58c142a090f58").val( importe_total );
  $("input#acf-field_58c13e2ed4e42").val( format_number_two_decimal( importe_neto ) );

    //debug purposes
  console.log( importe_neto );
 };

 $(document).on('change', 'input#acf-field_58c13e2ed4e42', function () {
  calculartotal();
 }); 

    /**
     * on page load
     */
    $(function(){
        calculartotal();
    });

})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fac_importe_neto" class="acf-field acf-field-number acf-field-58c13e2ed4e42" data-name="fac_importe_neto" data-type="number" data-key="field_58c13e2ed4e42">
 <div class="acf-label">
  <label for="acf-field_58c13e2ed4e42">Importe neto</label>
 </div>
 <div class="acf-input">
  <div class="acf-input-wrap"><input type="number" id="acf-field_58c13e2ed4e42" class="acf-is-appended" min="" max="" step="any" name="acf[field_58c13e2ed4e42]" value="" placeholder=""></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="fac_importe_total" class="acf-field acf-field-number acf-field-58c142a090f58" data-name="fac_importe_total" data-type="number" data-key="field_58c142a090f58">
 <div class="acf-label">
  <label for="acf-field_58c142a090f58">Importe total</label>
 </div>
 <div class="acf-input">
  <div class="acf-input-wrap"><input type="number" id="acf-field_58c142a090f58" class="acf-is-appended" min="" max="" step="any" name="acf[field_58c142a090f58]" value="" placeholder=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works like a charm, but I want to completely remove in the whole script the references to the number id that my framework automatically generates (i.e. acf-field_58c142a090f58) and use instead the more semantic ids (written by me).

NOTE: The framework don't allows me to put semantic ids in the input fields, so...

I was trying to use the parent div id, which name actually I can control, i.e. "fac_importe_neto" as follows:

```
var importe_neto = $("#fac_importe_neto").find("input").value;
```

With no success... What I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try keep using jquery with `val()`:

```
var importe_neto = $("#fac_importe_neto").find("input").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use javascript in jquery

```
var importe_neto = $("#fac_importe_neto").find("input").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case we want to use **.value** the **.get()** method needs to be applied as follows:

```
var importe_neto = $("#fac_importe_neto").find("input").get(0).value;
```